# MockHttpServletRequest ignoring set fields, how do I get around this?

Tags: java, servlets, spring-test

I am trying to test a servlet filter for a Tomcat application. To do so, I am using the MockHttpServletRequest provided by Spring.

I set it up like this:

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
request.setMethod("POST");
request.setRemoteHost("mycompany.com");
request.setRequestURI("/myapp.php");
request.setSecure(true);
```

but when I the following:

```
System.out.println(request.getRequestURL());
```

produces: `http://localhost/myapp.php`. On the other hand, if I explicitly request one of the fields I set, like:

```
System.out.println(request.getRemoteHost());
```

I get: `mycompany.com`

What's going on here? How can I get `getRequestURL` to produce what I'm really after: `https://mycompany.com/myapp.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sotirios was correct regarding the `serverName` vs. `remoteHost`; however, that change only gets you partially there.

The following will achieve your goal:

```
MockHttpServletRequest request = new MockHttpServletRequest();
request.setScheme("https");
request.setServerName("mycompany.com");
request.setServerPort(443);
request.setRequestURI("/myapp.php");

System.out.println(request.getRequestURL());
// Prints: https://mycompany.com/myapp.php
```

Regards,

Sam

Answer (score 1):

You're creating a [`MockHttpServletRequest`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html) which represents a request which a servlet, running on a server, received.

The javadoc of [`MockHttpServletRequest#getRemoteHost()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteHost--) (really of [`ServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html?is-external=true#getRemoteHost--)) states

> Returns the fully qualified name of the **client** or the last proxy that
>   sent the request.

So what you're setting with `setRemoteHost` is the hostname/ip of the client making the request, not the hostname of the server receiving the request.

You'll want [`MockHttpServletRequest#setServerName(String)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mock/web/MockHttpServletRequest.html#setServerName-java.lang.String-)

```
request.setServerName("mycompany.com");
```